# Visual Studio 2017 create .map and .js files from .ts typescript file

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I have been working through the hero tutorial from the angular.io site using Visual Studio 2017.   I've tried adding a .ts file but no matching .map or .js files are created.

My tsconfig.json looks like this

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "buildOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true

  },
  "include": [
    "./*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

If I remove this file to use the project's properties, rather than the config file, then the project won't compile, nor do the files build.

How do I get the .map and .js files to be created on build or on the creation of a new .ts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Angular CLI since you are doing the hero tutorial.

Is webpack running smoothly?  Can you please post the folder structure you have an the output of `ng serve`?

---

### EDIT

We spoke in chat and discussed some architecture and setup.

Comment: At the moment, nothing seems to be working
tsc -v brings back Version 2.5.2
ng -v
    _                      _                 ____ _     ___
   / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
  / â–³ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
 / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
/_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
               |___/
@angular/cli: 1.3.2
node: 8.1.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.3.6
@angular/compiler: 4.3.6
@angular/core: 4.3.6
@angular/forms: 4.3.6
@angular/http: 4.3.6

Comment: @angular/platform-browser: 4.3.6
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.3.6
@angular/router: 4.3.6
@angular/cli: 1.3.2
PM>

Comment: npm install -g @angular/compiler-cli
returns the error
npm : npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.0-RC.0 requires a peer of typescript@^2.0.2 but none was installed.

Comment: So I've got a higher version of typescript than required, but it doesn't recognise it as installed despite both being installed globally

Comment: @Glyn - what does ng serve do?

Comment: ng : The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
At line:1 char:1

Comment: Sounds like you are missing some npm packages.  I would reinstall:
npm -i

Comment: I've got typescript 2.5.2 which is more than 2.0.2

Comment: I've tried forcing the install using -f, that returns the same error

Comment: I've also tried installing typescript 2.0.2 but that's a whole other bundle of error messages

Comment: This is Windows or Mac?  Is this your first project?  It seems like you have some basic setup issues.

Comment: Windows, this is the first thing I've tried, I've followed the tutorial through three times now to the same effect.  I've downloaded the sample project too and that fails as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153892/discussion-between-matt-knight-and-glyn).

Comment: @Glyn - Please mark my answer if you feel I have been helpful via chat.